# Landsat 8 Composite Image - Which Band Composition should I use?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, landsat

I've downloaded a Landsat 8 images (Band 1-7) and used ArcGIS to make a Composite Image. Then I set the color bands:

```
Red - 4
Green - 3
Blue - 2
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is a glacier in Iceland, so I expected a lot more green. From EarthExplorer website, I assume this is what it should look like:

[image]

Source: https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/gen-browse?size=rrb&type=refl&product_id=LC08_L1TP_217015_20150925_20200908_02_T1

ESRI posted this article: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/imagery/band-combinations-for-landsat-8/ about using different band compositions to highlight specific features. Should I use one of those combinations or am I missing a step that would make my Natural Color correct?

Comment: I see you have the stretch type set to percent clip.  Try setting that to 'none'.